# How to get data from two tables using join in peewee Python

Tags: python, peewee

There are two tables inherited from Model.  Suppose their names are `Table1` and `Table2`.  We get some fields:

```
res = Table1.select (Table1.name, Table2.token) .join (Table2, on = (Table1.id == Table2.id
```

If receive
 `res.name`, it will display the name, and when `res.token` is received, an error occurs that `Table1` does not contain a token field.

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Table1' object has no attribute 'token'

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered numerous times before. Peewee resolves joined models into a model graph. So you would use:

```
query = (Tweet
         .select(Tweet.content, User.username)
         .join(User, on=(Tweet.user == User.id)))
for tweet in query:
    # YOUR CODE:
    print(tweet.username, tweet.content)

    # CORRECT:
    print(tweet.user.username, tweet.content)
```

As you can hopefully see, Peewee has placed the "username" field onto the "user" instance related to the tweet.

If you want to simply put *all* selected attributes onto the initial model, then use the ".objects()" method:

```
# Add .objects() to patch all attributes onto the tweet instance.
for tweet in query.objects():
    # Now "username" is an attribute on tweet:
    print(tweet.username, tweet.content)
```

Read the docs. Please. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html